# Datalogic Scanner-Write Data to File

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have a Datalogic PM8300-DK Scanner that is working fine so far. I choose the USB-KBD-Mode (USB INTERFACE SELECTION) and now everytime I scan a barcode, the data-representation of the barcode is writen on my computer (where the cradle is connected to).

But the problem is, the data is writen to where the cursor stands (where the focus is). For example, when the focus is in a text-editor, the scanner writes the data to the text-editor. When the focus is in the google-search-box of my browser, it writes the barcodes to the search-box.

I would prefer if the data would be writen directly to a file, and there would be no output to the screen directly. Is that possible, does anyone know a modus for that ?

Thanks, Andre

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the serial or USB serial emulation (COM port) connection for that.  You will also need to have some software to handle the data.